# nginx rewrite to remove date path of legacy URLs

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I have an issue where I am trying to use nginx to remove some legacy information from a URL however it's a date but it always follows the same format:

```
http://example.com/blog/xxxx/xx/xx/this-is-a-blog-post/
```

To..

```
http://example.com/blog/this-is-a-blog-post/
```

I wonder if this is possible? I've had a go at trying to write it myself, but I'm having trouble picking out only the middle part. Is this possible with a re-write rule?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: It isn't no, the URL structure was changed quite some time ago but still seeing people hit the old URLs and wondered if there was an easy fix with rewrite rules.

Answer (score 4):

After some playing around and testing I managed to achieve this using the following statement:

```
rewrite "/blog/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)" /blog/$4 permanent;
```

The first part matches the following expression:

```
/blog/2013/01/01/
```

Anything after the last slash will be used to build the new URL, this is used with a $4 as $ can be used to reference each () the first three are year, month, day and the final set matches the title of the blog post which is why I used $4.

Hope this helps people, thanks to Mohammad in the comments for getting me on the correct lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
rewrite /blog/[0-9]{4}(?:/[0-9]{2}){2}(?<new_uri>.*) /blog$new_uri last;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately it didn't work and returned an error 

directive "rewrite" is not terminated by ";"

But I used your example combined with the documentation to get my along the right lines, thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: probably because of the `{ }` it needs to be written in a string, you could have replied saying it won't work and I would have helped, but glad you got it working at the end